# How to create 5 rating stars with AngularJS which the third one is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to add a constraint when a user rates a business. **User should not be able to vote 3** because it is the default rate given by the system to any new added business to our database.

I am using AngularJS as a front-end Javascript library and to create the rating bar, I am using **ui.bootstrap.rating** module.

What I want to do is something like this (the case when user clicks on the fourth star)
[image]

What I tried is this

Html code

```html
<uib-rating ng-model="rateNumber1" max="2"
            state-on="'fullStar'" state-off="'emptyStar'"
            aria-labelledby="custom-icons-1"
            read-only="false">
</uib-rating>
<uib-rating ng-model="rateNumber2" max="1"
            state-on="'thirdStar'" state-off="'emptyStar'"
            on-hover="onHoverRatingNumber2()" on-leave="onLeaveRatingNumber2()"
            aria-labelledby="custom-icons-1"
            read-only="false">
</uib-rating>
<uib-rating ng-model="rateNumber3" max="2"
            state-on="'fullStar'" state-off="'emptyStar'"
            on-hover="onHoverRatingNumber3()" on-leave="onLeaveRatingNumber3()"
            aria-labelledby="custom-icons-1"
            read-only="false">
</uib-rating>
```

Javascript functions created in the controller for this purpose

```js
/* rating a business */
$scope.rateNumber1 = 0;
$scope.rateNumber2 = 0;
$scope.rateNumber3 = 0;
$scope.onHoverRatingNumber3 = function () {
  $scope.rateNumber1 = 2;
  $scope.rateNumber2 = 1;
};
$scope.onLeaveRatingNumber3 = function () {
  $scope.rateNumber1 = 0;
  $scope.rateNumber2 = 0;
};
$scope.onHoverRatingNumber2 = function () {
  $scope.rateNumber1 = 2;
};
$scope.onLeaveRatingNumber2 = function () {
  $scope.rateNumber1 = 0;
};
```

CSS classes to create custom rating icons

```css
.emptyStar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/ratingStars/empty.png");
}

.fullStar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/ratingStars/full.png");
}

.thirdStar {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/ratingStars/thirdStar.png");
}
```

Comment: What happens if the user votes 2 and then wants to change it back to 3? Just out of curiosity really, its got nothing to do with solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **rating-states** setting of **ui.bootstrap.rating** module.

From the doc

> **rating-states** (Default: null) - An array of objects defining
>   properties for all icons. In default template, stateOn & stateOff
>   property is used to specify the icon's class.

First, you should specify your rating states in your controller

```
$scope.ratingStates = [
    {stateOn: 'fullStar', stateOff: 'emptyStar'},
    {stateOn: 'fullStar', stateOff: 'emptyStar'},
    {stateOn: 'thirdStar', stateOff: 'emptyStar'},
    {stateOn: 'fullStar', stateOff: 'emptyStar'},
    {stateOn: 'fullStar', stateOff: 'emptyStar'}
  ];
```

Then create a function to reset the rating to zero when the third star is clicked (to prevent the user from choosing 3 as a rate)

```
 $scope.changeRate = function(r){
    if(r==3){
      $scope.rate=0;
    }
  };
```

Finally group all together in your html

```
<uib-rating ng-change="changeRate(rate)" 
            ng-model="rate"    
            rating-states="ratingStates" 
            aria-labelledby="custom-icons-2">
</uib-rating>
```

Here is a working [example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/k7oLIgcvbRu62lHSZl2P?p=preview)

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know that I can choose a specific icon for each rate. Thank you.